# How to change the python interpreter for ipython on mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, python-2.7, macos-sierra

I have python libraries in the following folders on my mac

- `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`
- `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`

and, the corresponding binaries as the following files

- `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`
- `/usr/local/bin/python3.6`

But, the ipython binary is in `/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.2.1/bin/ipython` and the ipython file `/usr/local/bin/ipython` has the following line in it -

`PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.2.1/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.2.1/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.6/site-packages" exec "/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.2.1/libexec/bin/ipython" "$@"`

Therefore, on executing ipython in the terminal the default interpreter is taken as python3.6 by the system. How can I modify these files to change the python interpreter from 3.6 to 2.7?

Following is a screenshot of all the ipython* files in my mac.

[image]

Comment: why don't you use a virtual environment instead?

Comment: True! that's always an option. But, I am adamant on fixing this by writing some scripts or changing the paths. ***OCD mode on***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 6, IPython is no longer compatible with Python 2.x.

You can either keep using IPython 6 with Python 3 or downgrade to IPython 5 and use Python 2.

http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version6.html#ipython-6-0
https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/2849

Comment: Thank you very much @orangeInk